# How to re-scale a five point likert scale into three catagories

Tags: data-transformation, likert

Can anyone help me in re-scaling a five point likert scale into three categories using the mean scores. I have used a 5 point likert scale:

```
 (1) Not at all, (2) low, (3) moderate, (4) high and (5) very high
```

Now I want to categorize these into `Low`, `Moderate` and `High`, but I am not sure how to use use the result. I planned try it like this:

1. less than 2.5  = `Low`
2. between 2.5 and 3.5 = `Moderate**
3. greater than 3.5 = `High`

Comment: Without any more information than this, how do you suppose anyone would be able to answer? You tell us nothing about the context or your purpose and both are essential for providing objective, good advice.

Comment: There is probably no good reason to recategorize. In addition to @whuber 's requests, you should give us the frequencies of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused by your categories.  When you say less than 2.5 is low, are you meaning to say less than or equal to 2 would be low?  Or have you given a questionnaire with many questions on a five point scale, and then you are taking a person's average score and trying to categorize them into one of 3 categories?